# Are there nice ways to solve $(2+x)^{0.25}-(2-x)^{0.25}=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Are there nice and elegant ways to solve this equation?

$(2+x)^{0.25}-(2-x)^{0.25}=1$

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Let $A=\sqrt{2+x}$ and $B=\sqrt{2-x}$.  See if you can show the following two equations hold:

$$A^2+B^2=4$$

$$2A+2AB+2B=5$$

Adding these two equations together, and using the quadratic formula you should be able to show that $A+B=\sqrt{10}-1$.  Then, plugging this into the second equation, and using the fact that $AB=\sqrt{4-x^2}$, you will obtain the equation

$$7-2\sqrt{10}=2\sqrt{4-x^2}$$

Solving for $x$ gives

$$x=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{28\sqrt{10}-73}$$

Comment: This nicely evades having to solve a quartic equation.  Otherwise, everyone _is_ getting (different expressions for) the same number, $ \ x \ \approx \ 1.9712797 \ $ .

Answer (score 1):

Let $t = 2 + x$, and $u = 2 - x$, then $u + t = 4$, and $t^{1/4} - u^{1/4} = 1$. Again let $p = t^{1/4}$, and $q = u^{1/4}$, then $p - q = 1$, and $p^4 + q^4 = 4$. So $(q+1)^4 + q^4 = 4$ and this gives: $2q^4 + 4q^3 + 6q^2 + 4q - 3 = 0$. Solving this we have:
$q = \dfrac{-1 + \sqrt{2\sqrt{10} - 3}}{2}$, and $u = q^4 = \dfrac{\left(-1 + \sqrt{2\sqrt{10} - 3}\right)^4}{16}$. So $x = 2 - u = 2 - \dfrac{\left(-1 + \sqrt{2\sqrt{10} - 3}\right)^4}{16}$

Comment: How do you solve your last equation?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call this nice but it works!

Subtract $\sqrt[4]{x+2}$ from both sides $$-\sqrt[4]{2-x}=1-(x+2)^{{1}/{4}}.$$
Raise both sides to the power of four:
$$2-x=\left(1-(x+2)^{{1}/{4}}\right)^4$$
Subtract $\left(1-(x+2)^{{1}/{4}}\right)^4$ from both sides
$$2-x-\left(1-(x+2)^{{1}/{4}}\right)^4=0 \\
\iff 4 (x+2)^{3/4}+4 (x+2)^{{1}/{4}}-2 x-6 \sqrt{x+2}-1=0
$$
Simplify and substitute $y=\sqrt[4]{x+2}\,\,$in $4 (x+2)^{3/4}+4 (x+2)^{{1}/{4}}-2 x-6 \sqrt{x+2}-1=-6 \left((x+2)^{{1}/{4}}\right)^2+4 \left((x+2)^{{1}/{4}}\right)^3-2 \left((x+2)^{{1}/{4}}\right)^4+4 (x+2)^{{1}/{4}}+3=-2 y^4+4 y^3-6 y^2+4 y+3=0.$
We multiply both sides by $-1$: $$2 y^4-4 y^3+6 y^2-4 y-3=0.$$

Eliminate the cubic term by substituting $z=y-\dfrac{1}{2}$:
$$-3-4 \left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)+6 \left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-4 \left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)^3+2 \left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)^4=0$$
Expand out terms of the LHS: $$2 z^4+3 z^2-\frac{31}{8}=0.$$
Now we substitute $u=z^2$: $$2 u^2+3 u-\frac{31}{8}=0.$$
This is a quadratic equation, its solution is given by the quadratic formula and after simplification it is: $$
u=\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{3}{4}\quad\color{grey}{\text{or}}\quad u=-\frac{3}{4}-\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}.$$
Substitute back $z^2$ we get: $$
z^2=\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{3}{4}\quad\color{grey}{\text{or}}\quad z^2=-\frac{3}{4}-\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}\\ \iff 
z=\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{3}{4}}\quad\color{grey}{\text{or}}\quad z=-\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{3}{4}}\\\quad\quad\color{grey}{\text{or}}\quad z=\sqrt{-\frac{3}{4}-\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}}\quad\quad\color{grey}{\text{or}}\quad z=-\sqrt{-\frac{3}{4}-\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}}.$$
Since we're solving over the reals, we can get rid of those two last solutions. 
Substitute back $z=y-\dfrac12$: $$
y-\frac{1}{2}=\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{3}{4}}
\quad\color{grey}{\text{or}}\quad
y-\frac{1}{2}=-\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{3}{4}}
\\
\iff 
y=\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{3}{4}}
\quad\color{grey}{\text{or}}\quad
y=\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{3}{4}}
$$
Substitute back for $y=\sqrt[4]{x+2}$:
$$
\sqrt[4]{x+2}=\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{3}{4}}
\quad\color{grey}{\text{or}}\quad
\sqrt[4]{x+2}=\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{3}{4}}\\
\iff 
\sqrt[4]{x+2}^4=\left(\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{3}{4}}\right)^4
\quad\color{grey}{\text{or}}\quad
\sqrt[4]{x+2}^4=\left(\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{3}{4}}\right)^4
$$
Assuming $x+2>0$:
$$
x+2=\left(\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{3}{4}}\right)^4
\quad\color{grey}{\text{or}}\quad
x+2=\left(\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{3}{4}}\right)^4 \\
\iff 
x=\left(\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{3}{4}}\right)^4-2
\quad\color{grey}{\text{or}}\quad
x=\left(\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{3}{4}}\right)^4-2
$$
Since we've done a lot of substitution, we may have added some spooky additional solutions, we check  and we find that indeed there's an additional solution which is the second one. So the solution to our problem is:

$$
\color{grey}{\boxed{\color{white}{\overline{\underline{\,\,\color{black}{x=\left(\dfrac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\sqrt{\dfrac{5}{2}}-\dfrac{3}{4}}\right)^4-2}\,\,}}}}}
$$